# How to split large XML webservice applications in microservices?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, rest, servlets

I have a `XML` `webservice` application that consists of several parts. There is a common entry `servlet` that delegates to different internal webservices based on the `request parameters`.

Now I wonder which solution might be better:

- to have any of those services running within a single application? So, one application serves all?
- or split them into microservices, where each servlet app is responsible for only one single purpose/brand?

Example: lets assume we have a common `car` service that serves content for all cars of a brand. Each of them might have completely different logic.

- Some brands might have periodic data imports.
- Some brands might get data from additional an external webservice.
- Some brands might have a database cache, etc.

`/my/rest/car/AUDI/details?id=123`

`/my/rest/car/BMW/details?id=456`

`...`

Most of those webservices are nearly independent. Though they are currently contained within a single application, as they all serve "car content".

Now I'm rethinking if it could make sense having the common `/my/rest/car/{brand}` webservice servlet in a main `war` file. And then create a new war file for each of the brands. Each of them would offer its own XML `webservice`, and the common servlet would delegate and join them.

Of course, this might result in a bit overhead, as the xml `request` and `response` has to be exchanged locally between those services.

But as an advantage, I could more easily maintain and restart each service individually without downtime of the others, and would have less side effects refactoring and extending a part. Eg if there is only one data import change for BWM.

So, what is your experience in splitting large applications like this? One serves all, or single services?

Comment: Are you aware of http://microservices.io/patterns/microservices.html and When Should I Use Them? at http://martinfowler.com/microservices/ ?

Comment: Well, there is not much concret written about when to chose microservices, and when not...